# How do I access the Focused detail View?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xaf

How do I get the focused detail view in an XAF App?

I have an event that fires for every Detail View I have open in my app. But I only need it to fire for the focused or selected Detail View.
How can I access the Focused or Selected DetailView and tell the event to fire only if the detail view is the focused View?

Answer (score 0):

In a Controller, you have the "View" and "Frame" properties.

As [controllers are not shared between windows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112608), XAF create brand new frames, controller and actions instances for each view you open.

Reading more about your problem [in another ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034851/event-keeps-firing-for-every-window-i-have-open), I can tell the event you mentioned is called outside the current Frame scope, which causes the problem; New windows are open and new controllers instances plugs their events to the very same Control, causing them all to fire at once.

You normally don't need to worry about focused Window. Just create your action/event inside a controller on a View and you will be fine. See also: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112737

Comment: So if I assign a Controller to a specific View. Like View.ID = BookingDetailView, it will only fire for that DetailView correct?

Comment: My problem is, If I have 3 BookingDetailViews open, the event will fire 3 times. How do I call the event inside the scope of the Frame?

Comment: The problem is in the action/button that fires the Report. This action must  also be placed inside a frame, and recreated for each new view, just like the other XAF actions. If you need more help with this, you can post the code that holds the report action.